# ¿Cómo hacer un "multiselect" para filtro de columnas en dataTable JQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables, select, checkbox, multiselect

He hecho una tabla con filtrado por columnas en un dataTable, pero quisiera que el select que tengo, se cambie a un "multiselect" para que el filtrado sea un poco mas practico, les comparto el codigo que implemente:

```
data:result,
        initComplete: function ()
         {
            this.api().columns([1,2,3,4,5,6]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class= "form-control"><option value="">Filtrar</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
               var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
               $(this).val()
            );
            column
               .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
               .draw();
            } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
           } );                 
               
         }
```

De antemano, muchas gracias amig@s